# PHP PDO Statements with a WHERE IN statement?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I am not too sure if I fully understand what I need to ask here but heres the situation. I am trying to make some changes to a legacy application which is using CodeIgniter.

There is a function that currently accepts a `userID` and a `groupID`. I need to adjust this so that I can pass an array of groupID's instead.

```
/*
  $userID INT
  $groupID Array of Ints
*/
public function check_user_in_group($userid, $groupid) 
{
    $s = $this->db->where("userid", $userid)->where("groupid", $groupid)->get("user_group_users");
    if($s->num_rows() == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Is there an `IN` clause that I can use in a situation like this?

Essentially I am trying to say `WHERE groupid IN [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->where_in()
```

Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with AND if appropriate. Example Below:

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
```

Comment: sometimes its just too obvious :x - Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. thats why we need each other to remind things hahah